# Inequality for eigenvalues of two positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A+A^{\rm T}>0$. I am trying to prove (or disprove by counterexample) that 
\begin{equation}
\big(\lambda_{\max}(A+A^{\rm T})\big)^2\geq4\lambda_{\min}(A^{\rm T}A).
\end{equation}
Numerical investigations suggest that the inequality holds, but I have no idea how to prove it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does ORHP mean? Also, does $R$ come from $A = QR$?

Comment: ORHP means open-right-half complex plane. R was a typo.

Comment: Since $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues/vectors, what you want to prove is equivalent to proving $(\lambda_{max}(A))^2 \geq \lambda_{min}(A^T A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false.  Consider 
$$
A = t\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0} + \epsilon I \qquad t,\epsilon > 0
$$
Note that $A + A^T = 2\epsilon I$, and $A^TA = (t^2 + \epsilon^2)I$.  As such, we have
$$
[\lambda_{max}(A + A^T)]^2 = 4\epsilon^2\\
4\lambda_{min}(A^TA) = 4(t^2 + \epsilon^2)
$$
Clearly, the desired inequality does not hold in general.

Comment: I upvoted, but technically your matrix $A + A^T$ doesn't satisfy the OP's condition that $A + A^T$ must be positive definite.

Comment: @abmar Good catch.  Fixed the answer accordingly.